# How do I create a custom launch screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, screen, launch

I am making a Flutter app where I have a list on the second screen that is very time consuming to build. So I thought of kind of a Launch Screen or Widget I show to the user while the list is building in the background.

I have a boolean variable `isLoading` that should change to `false` if the list is fully loaded.

How can I achieve that?

Here is the code from my main.dart:

```
import 'package:LaunchScreen/screen2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Launch Screen', theme: ThemeData(), home: MyHome());
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  static var isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Launch Screen',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Launch Screen"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: isLoading
              ? Center(
                  child: Text("Loading..."),
                )
              : Screen2(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the code of the Widget where the list should be displayed:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> myList = [
  "Afghanistan",
  "Albania",
  "Algeria",
  "Andorra",
  "Angola",
  "Antigua and Barbuda",
  "Argentina",
  "Armenia",
  "Australia",
  "Austria",
  "Azerbaijan",
];

class countryList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(myList[i]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's not a big deal to load a few list items, but later it should load a whole list via json.

Comment: First, you need to convert StatelessWidget to StatefulWidget and after coming data, call setState() method to rebuild your page

Comment: But I think the widget will never be loaded because of my conditional expression.

Comment: Take a look here, it will help you https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Answer (score 0):

First:

1. Convert `myHome` to `StatefulWidget`.
2. `isLoading` should not be static. It belongs to the Widget's state.

Then, you can proceed with your state logic. What you will do display the loading page by *default*, so we will do `isLoading = true`, and then when you're done rendering whatever, you can use `setState` to trigger the `build()` function to run again, but this time with `isLoading = false`.

Here is the example `build()` method inside `_MyHomeState`, and you can view the full example [**on DartPad**](https://dartpad.dev/0fa8539de4691a0b2559fac96a1652ae). For this example, we will call `setState` by clicking a button, but you could call it from anywhere inside `_MyHomeState`, i.e. after your `ListView` renders.

```dart
bool isLoading = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Launch Screen',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Launch Screen"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: isLoading
            ? Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("Loading..."),
                      RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Press me!"),
                          onPressed: () => setState(() => isLoading = false))
                    ]),
              )
            : Screen2(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```